# get all period attendance of each student

Tags: mysql

I've three table like attendance, period and status. To get my output I wrote this query

```
SELECT * FROM status s 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT period_id,p_name,student_id,date,status 
    FROM period p 
    LEFT JOIN attendance a 
    ON p.period_id=a.period_id)t1
ON s.status=t1.status
```

But it's not giving the desired output...can anyone help

Attendance:

```
--------------------------------------------------------- 
id | student_id | period_id    |date       | Status     |
--------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 1            |2016-12-24 | Present
--------------------------------------------------------|
2  | 1          | 3            |2016-12-24 | Absent     
--------------------------------------------------------|
3  | 2          | 1            |2016-12-24 | Late    
--------------------------------------------------------|
4  | 2          | 2            |2016-12-24 | Present
```

Period:

```
-----------------------
period_id  |  p_name   | 
-----------------------
1          |  period1  |
-----------------------
2          |  period2  |
-----------------------
3          |  period3  |
```

status:

```
-------------------
id    |  status   |
-------------------
1     |  Present  |
-------------------
2     |  Absent   |
-------------------
3     |  Late
```

Output

```
-----------------------------------------------------
student_id   |  period_id |  date        |  Status  |
-----------------------------------------------------
1            |  1         |  2016-12-24  |  Present |
-----------------------------------------------------
1            |  2         |  2016-12-24  |  null    |
-----------------------------------------------------
1            |  3         |  2016-12-24  |  Absent  |
-----------------------------------------------------
2            |  1         |  2016-12-24  |  Late    |
-----------------------------------------------------
2            |  2         |  2016-12-24  |  Present |
-----------------------------------------------------
2            |  3         |  2016-12-24  |   null
```

Comment: You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The first table in a `LEFT JOIN` has to be one that contains all the rows you want in the result. In your case, this should be the full cross product of all the distinct students, dates, and periods. So the query should be:

```
SELECT s.student_id, p.period_id, d.date, a.status
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT student_id FROM attendance) AS s
CROSS JOIN period AS p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM attendance) AS d
LEFT JOIN attendance AS a
ON a.student_id = s.student_id AND a.period_id = p.period_id AND a.date = d.date
ORDER BY d.date, s.student_id, p.period_id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e815/2)

There doesn't appear to be any need for the `status` table, since you redundantly have the status names in the `attendance` table, rather than `status_id`.